# SQL Subquery with SUMs

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, subquery

I have the following query from a Ledger table in my accounting database:

```
select  lmatter
        , ltradat
        , llcode
        , lamount
        , lperiod
from    ledger  
where   lmatter = '1234-ABCD'
        and lzero <> 'R'
order by lperiod
```

The results are:

[image]

From this, I want to know if it is possible to create a final result of:

[image]

The way I got these #'s is as follows:

We are working under the assumption that today is December 1st, 2015 and we are billing for November 2015 data. Which makes the **lperiod** we're working with as "current" equal to '1115'

- *Matter ID* is a distinct **lmatter**
- *Prev. Bal* is SUM(FEES + HCOST) - SUM(PAY) where **lperiod** <> '1115'
- *Payments* is SUM(PAY) where **lperiod** = '1115'
- *Current Charges* is SUM(FEES + HCOST) where **lperiod** = '1115'
- *Amount Due* is **Prev.Bal** - **Payments** + **Current Charges**

Is this possible under one query with use of sub-queries, or possibly even the use of a couple temp tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use case
you can build up more advanced logic
for Amount Due I would have nested query

```
select *, prev - pay + current as 'DUE'
from 
(
select  lmatter
      , sum(case when lperiod <> '1115' and llcode in ('FEES', 'HCOST')  then  lamount  
                 when lperiod <> '1115' and llcode = 'PAY'               then -lamount   
            end) as 'prev'
      , sum(case when lperiod  = '1115' and llcode = 'PAY'                then  lamount  
            end) as 'payment' 
      , sum(case when lperiod  = '1115' and llcode in ('FEES', 'HCOST')  then  lamount     
            end) as 'current'             

from    ledger  
where   lmatter = '1234-ABCD'
and     lzero <> 'R'
group by by lmatter 
) as tt
```

Comment: This gave me exactly what I needed. Even on a multiple matter level (not just stating "where lmatter = 'xxxxx'"  Thank you!